# How do you flatten a Sequence of Sequence in DBIOaction SLICK?

Tags: scala, slick, flatten

Hey guys i am new in slick, how can I flatten this sequence of sequence? so that can return the commented code

```
    def insertIfNotExists(mapCountryStates: Map[String, Iterable[StateUtil]]): Future[Seq[Seq[StateTable]]] /*: Future[Seq[StateTable]]*/ = {
    val interaction = DBIO.sequence(mapCountryStates.toSeq.map { case (alpha2Country, statesUtil) =>
      val codes = statesUtil.map(_.alpha3Code)
      for {
        countryId <- Countries.filter(_.alpha2Code === alpha2Country).map(_.id).result.head
        existing <- States.filter(s => (s.alpha3Code inSet codes) && s.countryId === countryId).result
        stateTables = statesUtil.map(x => StateTable(0L, x.name, x.alpha3Code, countryId))
        statesInserted <- StatesInsertQuery ++= stateTables.filter(s => !existing.exists(x => x.alpha3Code == s.alpha3Code && x.countryId == s.countryId))
      } yield existing ++ statesInserted
    })

    db.run(interaction.transactionally)
  }
```

if I write it here:

val interaction = DBIO.sequence(...).**flatten**

or here:

db.run(interaction.**flatten**.transactionally)

[error] Cannot prove that Seq[Seq[StateRepository.this.StateTableMapping#TableElementType]] <:< slick.dbio.DBIOAction[R2,S2,E2].

but when the application runs, because the IDE does not detect it as an error:
[image]

[image]

I update my definition with **DBIO.fold:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be after `DBIO.fold`. This provides a way to take a number of actions and reduce them down to a single value. In this case, your single value is a `Seq[StateTable]` from a `Seq[Seq[StateTable]]`.

A sketch of how this could look might be...

```
def insertIfNotExists(...): DBIO[Seq[StateTable]] = {
  val interaction: Seq[DBIO[Seq[StateTable]]] = ...
  val startingPoint: Seq[StateTable] = Seq.empty
  DBIO.fold(interaction, startingPoint) {
    (total, list) => total ++ list
  }
}
```

It looks like the types will line up using fold. Hope it's of some use in your case.

There's some more information about fold in [Chapter 4](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#combining) of [Essential Slick](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html).

Comment: oops like I did not realize before, **fold** it's exactly what I was looking for, thanks @Richard Dallaway, now if I close my solution....

Answer (score 1):

A viable solution should be to flatten the sequence once the `Future` has been completed:

```
def insertIfNotExists(mapCountryStates: Map[String, Iterable[StateUtil]]): Future[Seq[StateTable]] = {
  val interaction = DBIO.sequence(mapCountryStates.toSeq.map { case (alpha2Country, statesUtil) =>
    val codes = statesUtil.map(_.alpha3Code)
    for {
      countryId <- Countries.filter(_.alpha2Code === alpha2Country).map(_.id).result.head
      existing <- States.filter(s => (s.alpha3Code inSet codes) && s.countryId === countryId).result
      stateTables = statesUtil.map(x => StateTable(0L, x.name, x.alpha3Code, countryId))
      statesInserted <- StatesInsertQuery ++= stateTables.filter(s => !existing.exists(x => x.alpha3Code == s.alpha3Code && x.countryId == s.countryId))
    } yield existing ++ statesInserted
  })

  db.run(interaction.transactionally).map(_.flatten)
}
```

Comment: that solution is what I was doing before returning in the controller, but I would like to flatten in the dbioaction, anyway, thank you very much, regards